# Category array of calendar event is empty when event comes from invitation on Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing an interface that shows the outlook calendar of several people from where I work.
My manager created a few categories to tag each event:
[image]

To get my events of the week, I make the following request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/my-email/calendarview?startdatetime=2018-08-26T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2018-09-01T23:59:59Z&$select=subject,categories,start,end,sensitivity
```

When I create **my own** event on my calendar with one of these categories, I receive the category on the response:

```
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "categories": [
            "Categoria Vermelha"
        ],
        "subject": "TESTE",
        "sensitivity": "normal",
        "start": {...},
        "end": {...}
    },...
```

**The problem is**: if I share this event to someone of some group (as an invitation or as a meeting), the content of the field "categories" doesn't propagate. So no one knows which category is the event.

So does anybody know if this is a bug? The Microsoft  documentation doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your descriptions and my test. The category does not show the category of the calendar when event comes from invitation.

We can post to the Microsoft product group on '[the voice of the user](http://%20https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)'.

Comment: Hi, kikang! I gave up using category after your comment. Now I'm sending the category as a string on the title of the event. I'll suggest this new feature on the Voice of the User. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Absolutely. Done